# Displaying Current Page Number Conditionally

Tags: pages, navigation

I want to display the current page number in the site. I want it to be conditional though so that it doesn't show up on the home/front page. Using the code below, the page number is being displayed at all.

```
<?php 
    $pageNumber = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    if(!is_front_page()) {
        echo "<div class='page-count'><?php echo '&ndash; $pageNumber &ndash;'; ?></div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`is_paged`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged) which checks if the current page number is 2 or above (and returns true if it is). [`is_front_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) checks 'if the main page is a posts or a Page'.

You've also used incorrect syntax (changed from a double quote to a single quote, and used `<?php` inside a string being echoed).

Untested, but the following should do what you want:

```
<?php 
    $pageNumber = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    if(is_paged()) {
        echo "<div class='page-count'> &ndash;".$pageNumber." &ndash;</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Stephen! is_paged() was the function I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

as `get_query_var('paged')` returns empty on the first page, this might work as well (untested):

```
<?php
  if( get_query_var('paged') ) echo "<div class='page-count'> &ndash;".get_query_var('paged')." &ndash;</div>";
?>
```